# Replacing a string with a different string on a table in sql

Tags: mysql, replace, xampp, substitution

Good afternoon people.

I'm trying to replace a result from a query in a particular column in sql. the table is as follows:

```
+-----------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
| firstName | lastName | major | minor | credits |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
| Owen      | McCarthy | Math  | CSCI  |       0 |
| Mary      | Jones    | Math  | CSCI  |      42 |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------+---------+
```

I need to change Math to Mathematics and CSCI to Computer Science. is there any particular code where I can replace that?

the code that I used to generate this table is this:

```
select firstName, lastname, major, minor, credits from student where major = 'Math' and minor = 'CSCI';
```

any help is appreciated, thanks and have a nice superbowl sunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a lookup table with a join.  That way, you can ensure that all substitutions use the same values.

Within a single query, though, you can use the `case` expression.  However, in your query, that is not even necessary because of the `where` clause.  Just use constants:

```
select firstName, lastname,
       'Mathematics' as major, 'Computer Science' as minor, credits
from student
where major = 'Math' and minor = 'CSCI';
```

Without the `where` clause, you would do:

```
select firstName, lastname,
       (case when major = 'Math' then 'Mathematics' else major end) as major,
       (case when minor = 'CSCI' then 'Computer Science' else minor end) as minor,
       credits
from student;
```

Comment: thanks for the support, this helps me understand better how SQL works and how powerful the query can be. Thanks for both examples

Answer (score 1):

You COULD change it to something like

```
select 
    firstName, 
    lastname, 
    CASE WHEN major="Math" THEN "Mathematics"
    ELSE major
    END as 'major',
    CASE WHEN minor="CSCI" THEN "Computer Science"
    ELSE minor
    END as 'minor',
    credits 
from student 
where major = 'Math' 
and minor = 'CSCI'
;
```

to handle them on a case-by-case basis purely in the select, but it sounds like you'd be better off changing the definitions in the student table via `update students set major = 'Mathematics' where major = 'Math';` (and similarly for CSCI) if you're able.

Comment: I could have changed the definitions but the required format was just to simply change those definitions. However, your answer was really helpful in terms of simplicity, and helps me understand how SQL works. thanks

Comment: Glad it helped.  In case it's not clear from the above, you can add additional [CASEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html) before the ELSE to handle other conversions.  And as Gordon said, ideally you would have a table of disciplines, and instead of storing a student's major as the string "Math" you'd store a numerical ID that points to an entry in the discipline table.  Your SELECT would then join students to disciplines based on that ID.